# Use a sub-domain for a API-gateway/Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-api-gateway

I am integrating a web-relay into AWS-service which makes call-outs to a predefined path (
`/some-fixed-path` and it can not be configured) and I want to intercept it using a lambda on dedicated sub-domain, to keep this separated from the rest of our service, so I want the call-out to be `http://subdomain.example.com/some-fixed-path`.

I have a domain (lets call it `example.com`) registered and I have a hosted-zone defined. How can i create a record-set in the hosted-zone and use it in the API-gateway definition? (The url must not contain the stage...)

In the API-gateway definition, there is a "Custom domain name" option, but I can't figure out how to point to a record from my hosted-zone.

Comment: will your service follow 301 redirects? I don't think you can define paths in route53. So you could setup an s3 bucket for subdomain.example.com/some-fixed-path and setup the redirect in s3 to go to the api gateway url(which would have to include the stage.) Kinda hacky but I think it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply be able to follow the instructions for [using a custom domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) and then adding an alias record in your hosted zone to the CloudFront distribution provided by the API Gateway console.

You'll want to configure your custom domain with the base path pointing to your deployed stage. At that point you can than create your resource at `some-fixed-path`.

**Note**: API Gateway currently requires all APIs to be HTTPS, so if your call out can't be changed to support HTTPS, API Gateway will not work for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has [a detailed guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) about how to do that exactly.

A few more things to pay attention to are:

1. Make sure you remember to re-deploy when you make any change to the API.
2. When you set up Base Path Mapping, make sure double check the API resource path and method. (For example, if you create the API gateway through lambda template, the API resource will be created under /{API name} instead of /).

A lot of people see Missing Authentication Token when they use API gateway for the first time due to those reasons.